# Inter application communication in iphone

Tags: iphone

I just wanted to know if there is any way to access a document from outside the application in iphone. For instance, I want to be able to send a word document from mail to my application. How can I achieve this?

Thanks  in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iPhone Apps are sandboxed. iPhone SDK does not allow you to go out of your sandbox

In simple terms when you build a application there will be a folder created for you and Apple doesnt provide you to access anything that is outside of that folder. All your resources are confined inside that folder.

But you can access some of specific items such as Address Book, Photo Library. But definitely not mails.

Comment: Thanks for the response but can we have any alternatives like say using URL for communication between the mail and my app?? Just a guess...

Comment: URL's are used mainly for web service parts. I guess its impossible to retrieve mail services.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a blog that describes how inter-app communication works in iOS Apps.

[iOS Application Scheme support](http://knowledgetransferinobjectivec.blogspot.in/2012/04/inter-app-communication-document.html)

thanks,

Naveen Shan