# iOS Inter App Communication in Background

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipc, url-scheme

There is a platform application which connects to the remote server and stores required information in its local repository, that is in CoreData. I want to develop my application over this platform app. Since it is not possible to access its local storage, I have to communicate with it somehow. I am able to send/receive data using URL Schemes; however it's frustrating for user to switch between apps constantly.

Is it possible to communicate with another application via URL Schemes (or any other way) without bringing it to foreground?

Answer (score 1):

With few exceptions, such as receiving CoreLocation data in the background or being notified to wake up by a local notification, it is not possible in iOS for an application to "run in the background"

Comment: Nor can any 2 (non-Apple) iOS Apps talk to each other.

Comment: I couldn't get what you mean chown. They can communicate via URL Schemes.

Comment: @mkubilayk hi, how could two non iOS Apps communicate with each other via url scheme?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common query on Stack Overflow, the official iOS reply can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)
There are SO articles [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283590/inter-application-communication-in-ios) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264652/inter-application-communication-in-iphone).

Background data exchange is however not going to be a thing as there are restrictions on background app rules (so the URL transfer is going to foreground your second app)