# Inter Application Communication in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, interprocess

I already go [Inter application communication in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264652/inter-application-communication-in-iphone) but is it possible to communicate two ios apps.
 or alteast 
i want notify second app when something happens(event) in First app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) for more information on inter-app communication. This requires though that the other developer of the app you want to communicate with, handles a URL Scheme and you know what it is. Or that the developer supports the "share"capability in iOS. If you develop the apps that communicate, you should either create your own URL scheme or use [App-Groups](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW61). I hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry missed the last part, if you want to notify the other app about the change, and want to open the other app straight away use the URL Scheme

Comment: Are you actually talking about two apps you manage/develop or not? What type of changes do you want to be notified about? Could you be more specific what exactly you want to have happen as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264652/inter-application-communication-in-iphone this solution have url scheme but i want diffrenr

Comment: What exactly do you want? Could you elaborate?